# How to verify text order/position?

Tags: selenium, protractor

How can a protractor test verify the location and order of text on page? Our application generates schedules that is comprised of divs in specific orders depending on the date/time and type of activity.

I know the text itself can be verified but am not sure how to verify that they are in the correct order.

Ex: A needs to appear before B if C does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty convenient to do by calling `getText()` on an array of elements - this would produce an array of texts which, what important, is ordered the same way as elements are ordered:

```
var divs = $$(".someCommonDivClass");

expect(divs.getText()).toEqual(["first text", "second text", "third text"]);
```